# wrong redirect with capybara

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

I have problem in my previous question, me helped, but and now I've took new.
I'm make integration tests with rspec and capybara.

this my profiles_controllers.rb :

```
 before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def update
    @profile = current_user.profile
    if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
        flash[:success] = "Профиль обновлен!"
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

it's my test file:

```
describe "ProfilePages" do

subject { page }

describe "edit" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:profile) { FactoryGirl.create(:profile, user: user) }

before do
  login user
  visit edit_profile_path(profile)
end

it { should have_selector('h2', text: 'Заполните информацию о себе') }

describe "change information" do
  let(:new_city)  { "Ulan-Bator" }
  let(:new_phone) { 1232442 }
  let(:new_gamelevel) { "M2" }
  let(:new_aboutme)   { "nfsfsdfds" }
  let(:submit) { "Сохранить" }
  before do
    fill_in "Город",             with: new_city
    fill_in "Телефон",           with: new_phone
    select new_gamelevel,        from: "Уровень игры"
    fill_in "О себе",            with: new_aboutme
    click_button submit
  end
  specify { profile.reload.city.should  == new_city }
  specify { profile.reload.phone.should == new_phone }
  specify { profile.reload.gamelevel.should == new_gamelevel }
  specify { profile.reload.aboutme.should == new_aboutme }
end

describe "submitting to the update action" do
  before  { put profile_path(profile) }
  specify { response.should redirect_to(user_path(user)) }
end
end
end
```

And I have error:

Failure/Error: specify { response.should redirect_to(user_path(user)) }
       Expected response to be a redirect to http://www.example.com/users/1 but was a redirect to http://www.example.com/users/sign_in

I use Devise and have login helper in spec/support:

```
def login(user)
 page.driver.post user_session_path, 'user[email]' => user.email, 'user[password]'       =>    user.password
end
```

And `config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller` in spec_helper.rb

I tried use warden helper login_as ,  but have same error. How I understand it's don't start session, I'am right?

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with your app code, but the test code.

`response` object is for controller integration tests, and there is no such object in Capybara.

Normally you can use `page` object to check response information. And for path checking, a better approach is `current_path` or `current_url`.

So your code will work by:

```
current_path.should be(user_path(user))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it's doesn't work: ` undefined local variable or method `current_path' for #<Class:0x00000004810368>`